# removing duplicates labels in geoserver tiled wms

Tags: openlayers-3

i have hard time finding an example for avoiding duplicates labels in geoserver tiled wms through ol3. Any chance someone has a link or a piece of code ?
regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the centroid function to find the geometry in the label rule,  then most of the polygons will labelled correctly. The only other issue is where they fall near the edge of the tile,  then you need to set the gutter in GWC to allow them to run over.